# Trackpad not fully functioning after resume from sleep (Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, sleep, touchpad, macbook-pro, boot-camp

I am running Windows 7 x64 on a 2012 MacBook Pro via Boot Camp. Often, when Windows resumes from sleep, the trackpad does not function fully. Move and single click work, but two-finger click and two-finger scrolling do not.

I have found that it is possible to restore full trackpad functionality using Device Manager:

1. Human Interface Devices => Apple Multitouch and Apple Multitouch Mouse => Disable
2. Human Interface Devices => Apple Multitouch => Enable
3. Human Interface Devices => Apple Multitouch Mouse => Enable

Note that the order in which the devices are re-enabled is critical.

What could be causing the trackpad to only partially work? Is there anything I can do to fix the problem, and hence avoid the Device Manager procedure?

Answer (score 0):

Apple’s standard trackpad driver doesn’t work with the trackpad as well in Windows as it does in Mac OS X.

You could try [Trackpad++](http://trackpad.powerplan7.com/) :

> Trackpad++ is the world's first and only alternate Windows driver for
>   Apple Multi Touch and Force Touch trackpads found in Apple Macbook,
>   Macbook Pro / Retina and Air notebooks. Trackpad++ driver comes with a
>   Control Module, the comprehensive control panel.

See this [review](http://www.howtogeek.com/197485/3-tools-to-make-your-macs-hardware-work-better-in-windows-with-boot-camp/) for more info, including these remarks :

> comes with a graphical user interface for adjusting these preferences.
>   It provides many more options than Apple’s barebones Boot Camp Control
>   Panel does. However, just installing the driver should make your
>   trackpad work better.
>
> On 64-bit versions of Windows 7, 8, and 8.1, you’ll need to install
>   [Power Plan Assistant](http://www.powerplan7.com/home.htm) before Trackpad++. Power Plan Assistant will
>   disable driver signature enforcement, allowing you to click through a
>   warning message to install this unsigned driver.
>
> Trackpad++ is free, but expires each week and requires a re-download
>   and reinstall unless you “donate” to the developer to acquire a serial
>   key.

[image]

<sub>(I have no personal experience with this utility.)</sub>